# my program shows me just the last value of i

Tags: android, multithreading, textview

why this program shows me just the last value of i =4 in textview.

```
    Public class MainActivity extendsActivity {
        TextView counter;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            counter = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_counter);
            Thread t = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                                try {
                                    counter.setText("" + i);
                                    System.out.println("Value of i= " + i);
                                    sleep(100);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            t.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe because its changing every 10th of a second. Do the logs output the correct numbers?

Comment: Doesn't sleep take its arguments in milliseconds? Since you're only doing 5 iterations, the whole thing runs in 500ms

Comment: @MarcB yes [sleep()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long))

Comment: The problem I see here is that you are sleeping on the `UI Thread`, do  the `sleep()`, run the for loop on the worker thread and use the `runOnUIThread()` only for doing the `setText()`. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
sleep(100)
```

is not a very long sleep. You probably are just not noticing that it is updating the field very quickly. Try increasing the sleep to 1000

Comment: the same problem with sleep(1000)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but I think this is what you need.  Also, as others have said, you might want to increase the sleep time, just to make sure its working.  What about 1000 ms?

```
Thread t = new Thread()
{
   public void run() 
   {
      for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
      {
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
          {
             public void run() 
             {
                try 
                {
                   counter.setText(""+i );
                   System.out.println("Value of i= "+i);
                }      
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                 }
              }
           });
           sleep(100);
      }
   });
}
```

EDIT:
Also, you should know, that in your current implementation, the sleep() method is being executed on the UI thread, which (i'm guessing) you don't want.  In this implementation, the sleep is running on the runnable.

Comment: I haven't tested this code, but that's what this is doing.  It should update the number every 100 ms.  But just for the sake of testing, set it to like 1000ms so you can see it actually updating.

Answer (score 0):

increase sleep time so the change is visible to human eye.

```
sleep(2000);
```

(or) concat the existing text of the counter

```
counter.setText(counter.getText()+i);
```

But did you check your console? because it must have
Value of i= 1 to 4

Comment: i check my consle and i show a true counter, just i need but in textview not in console

Answer (score -1):

You should post setText to be executed at the MainThread, it's simple like:

```
counter.getHandler().post(new Runnable(){public void run(){counter.setText("" + i);}});
```

Comment: See the question. The OP is doing a `setText()` by using `runOnUIThread()`

Comment: can i used handler in my problem ?

Comment: `runOnUIThread` works just fine. See my comment on the question to solve your problem.

Comment: I didn't noticed the runOnUiThread. But Posting to a Handler will schedulle better a Runnable to be executed at the UI lifecycle.